# Website elements are getting hidden at 125% Recommended laptop zoom

Tags: screen-resolution

A project that I've been working on, has elements in a scroll. Like this below -

[image]

But, certain laptops come with 125% recommended zoom for 1920 X 1080 resolution -

[image]

When used that 125% recommended zoom, the elements in the scroll gets hidden, obviously.

[image]

Any solution for this?

Comment: We are gonna need to see some code if you want any help.

Comment: @ecg8 I'm just wondering what code should I post for this question related to laptop zoom percentage problem.

Comment: You tagged the question as CSS and media queries, so start by posting the relevant CSS and media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below media query will give some relief to the issue.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 900px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) {
   Add styles here.
}
```